# Excel sequential number to values in a list, skipping a column for the Vlookup formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2007, array-formulas

I'm trying to write a formula where it will fill out the rest of the column based on another column. Basically, fill out sequential numbers, AND if one of them repeats, skip the ones that repeat and go to the next one that doesn't.
So from this image:
[sequential 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLVL8.png)

to this:
[sequential 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgix2.png)
Also I wanted that 'blank' column B in between the two, because I am planning on adding a different type of column in between sometime in the future after the 'testing' phase.
I was trying to mess with this formula:
IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,MAX(A$1:A1)+1,VLOOKUP(C2,C$1:A1,2,0))
but I messed up the 'where' and the 'column' for VLOOKUP, as well as not including a 'skip if same value' formula.
Could anyone point me into the right direction, please?

Thank you!!

EDIT:
Is there a way to include a drop down list, where it doesn't show the spaces in between?
Something that would look like this:
[image: sequential_dropdown_list]
Which would be based on Column A, but without the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you had is pretty close. Just drop the VLOOKUP entirely, since you wanted the cells in between to be blank: `=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,MAX(A$1:A1)+1,"")`

PS you say you wanted the COUNTIF results greater than 1 to show blank, since you wanted to use that for a future case. I doubt not showing data there would come in handy later. What do you have in mind?

With given edit I recommend using: `=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(A:A<>"",A:A,""),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}))` note that the array-values `{}` are static, so if you add or remove values you have to review this array and add or remove values to it.
Replacing the indexed `A:A` with `B:B`: `=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(A:A<>"",A:A,""),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}))` would give you the unique values of column B, based on the counter in column A.

Best option is to upgrade to Office 365 where you could easily spill the desired result with `FILTER`-function.

Comment: oooh my bad. I meant column B, not the spaces in between the numbers. I worded it wrong haha oops

Comment: and Thank you!! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Is there a way to make an 'IF' 'THEN" where it will 'group' the same numbers? I am trying to make a dropdown button for it, where it will show the sequential numbers and not blanks in between.

Comment: I have edited my original question to reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case I recommend you using the following formula in column B: `=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1,))` and then refer to it in your drop down list like so: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)):INDEX(C:C,MAX(IF(B:B=A2,ROW(C:C),"")))` where `A2` contains the value to base your drop down value(s) on.

Comment: Or do you mean you want the drop-down to show all unique values only?

Comment: Yes, just unique values only for the drop down.

Comment: the formula you sent it's giving me an error when I try to refer it

Comment: When referencing the second formula, how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by referencing?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. You need to include the Sheet names in the ranges. And you u may need Ctrl+shift+enter for older Excel versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize your data so that the value you look up (C2) is to the left of the return value you want to find. In your case VLOOKUP(C2,C$1:D1,2,0),  your return value should be in D column.

Formula cell E2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C2,C2)=1,MAX(E$1:E1)+1,VLOOKUP(C2,C$1:D1,2,0))
```

Results:

[image: excel]

Comment: Is there a way to make an 'IF' 'THEN" where it will 'group' the same numbers? I am trying to make a dropdown button for it, where it will show the sequential numbers and not blanks in between.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand very well your question, can you show us expected output?

Comment: I added it to my original question under EDIT:. I also used the formula that P.b gave, as it was what I was looking for. The reason why I wanted the numbers on the left is because I will later replace those letters with other data, as well as adding more data in other columns and whatnot, so it will be easier to just add columns after C on mine, rather than replacing column C on yours , and then replacing Column F-Z and so on.